# Issues connecting to an Oracle Database 19c

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus, oracle19c

I am attempting to create and use an oracle DB.

Was able to create the DB using sql plus however when I attempt to connect to it via sqldeveloper I get the following error
`Status : Failure -Test failed: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection`

When I check that all services are running I notice OracleVssWriterORCL is not running.
However upon attempting to start it I get the following error:
`Windows could not start OracleVssWriterORCL service on local machine Error 0x80070005: Access is Denied`

This is my first time using Oracle for DB so any help is greatly appreciated.
I should also note this is on a windows 10 VM

Comment: Is the network listener service running? Your first error implies that it is not, or that the network connection is being blocked by a firewall.

Comment: How would I check that? I don't see it running in services

Comment: OracleListener service, or run "lsnrctl status" from a command prompt.

Comment: Output in cmd
`LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on 24-DEC-2020 11:31:38

Copyright (c) 1991, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=0.0.0.0)(PORT=1521)))
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00511: No listener
   64-bit Windows Error: 61: Unknown error
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00511: No listener
   64-bit Windows Error: 2: No such file or directory
`

Comment: You must start the listener service before you can make JDBC or any other network connections to the database.

Comment: Got that working now thanks! Other issues but I'm finding more on them than what I did for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated above my listener was not running and going into cmd using the `lsnrctrl start` command fixed that issue but now I get a `ORA-12505` error. Oh the fun of learning new things